# document.getElementbyId() returning null - Blazor Telerik Razor Page

Tags: javascript, .net-core, razor, telerik, blazor-webassembly

I have a razor component page, in which the @code section is overriding the OnAfterRenderAsync function and calling a script. So, by the time the script is called, the DOM is loaded with all elements. But the getElementById() function returns null. What is the reason?
This is the structure:
Razor:

```
 <TelerikDatePicker Id="EFFT_DT" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" @bind-Value="@pro"
                    Width="150px"></TelerikDatePicker>
 <span class="required">*</span>
```

JS:

```
<script suppress-error="BL9992">

     function attachFocusHandler(id, componentClass) {
     var element = document.getElementById(id); // Is NULL
    
     if (element) {             
       //Does not get here   
    }
}
</script>
```

CS Code:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("attachFocusHandler", "EFFT_DT", ".k-datepicker");
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);       
}
```

All this is happening in the same razor file.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns null when no element with that ID exists. Make sure you have the correct ID and that the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested out the scenario in an isolated sample and it appears that the JS finds the element by ID. Can you share more information about your setup? Meanwhile, check out this example that logs a text message in the console:

[Telerik REPL example](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wcvvuvFx51ikAG2e39)